# required attribute on textbox in html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, forms

I have a popover with a form inside. And It is already out and ready for submission, here is the code for the popover

```
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">Add new subject</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
     <form class="form-inline" id="pop-form" method="POST" action="../admin/module_add_subject.do">
          <div class="form-group">

          <!-- This input is what i'm talking about -->
          <input type="text" name="subjectName" id="subject-name" required="required" pattern="^[\S\s]{3,25}[A-z]+$" title="Only accept alphabet characters and length is minimum of 3 and max of 25 " placeholder="Subject name.."/>

          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="add-subject" ><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i></button>

       </div>
       <p></p>
       <p style="color:red" id="error-message"></p>
     </form>
</div>
```

The input above I'm sure the regex is working. When I change the `button` to `submit`the required is working perfectly fine but when I change it back to `button` then it is not working again.

The reason why my `submit` button is a `type="button"` because of this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-subject', function(e) {
     $.post('../admin/module_check_subject.do', { subjectName: $('#subject-name').val() },
    function( data ) {
        // if data from the database is empty string
        if( $.trim( data ).length != 0 ) {
        // hide pop-over
        $('#popover').popover('hide');
        // submit form
        $('#pop-form').submit();
        } else {
        $('#error-message').text('Subject already exist.' );            
        }           
    }
     })
    .fail( function () {
                bootbox.alert('Failed to check, please try again later.');
    });
});
```

**What I'm doing is on submit i'll check out first in my database if the input** `text` **in the textbox exist in the database, then if the** `text` **exist the database stop the submission of the form and display error at the**  `p` **tag**

Comment: Try changing to function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
     $.post... - except I cannot fathom why you do not just post the form and return the error if not ok and save the data if ok without submitting again

Answer (score 0):

By the [form submission algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm), validation is not performed when a form is submitted using the `submit()` method. The idea is, more or less, that when you submit a form with a script, your script should also carry out any checks deemed necessary.

Within your script, you can call the [`checkValidity()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity) method to carry out the normal validation that would be performed if the form were submitted with a submit button. Note that it performs static validation only.

Comment: I'm quite new to web development. I check out the link you gave me and I don't quite get it of how I will `checkValidity()` because it seems that It is a method of `HTML` so I'm wondering how.